# What is the encryption method that works without exchanging any public or private keys at all?

Tags: encryption

We are learning about encryption (e.g. RSA) in class at the moment and our teacher told us about a paper he had read (and didn't remember the name) which presented an interesting encryption method. The premise was that the method didn't require the exchanging of any key (no public key of the recipient of a message required) somehow. Does anyone have any idea which paper he read and could maybe link it below?

Comment: Ef hhjsk flsjgv fffj, ergreri o qdfd. Tddzkljfz gzof !

Comment: Was that really necessary?

Comment: Your teacher may be brilliant. Or have had a bad day.

Comment: @Ladan: yes, that tells you something.